# Alternative to if(x >= 200 && x <= 299)?

Tags: php, javascript, math

In PHP (or any similar language), is there a better alternative to:

```
if(x >= 200 && x <= 299){
   return 'ok';
}
```

My goal is to validate if a number is in the range of the 2xx code (for HTTP requests).
I don't like the double-if clause because I must define the end of the range, and for some reason it's not practical when doing various automated validations.

Comment: Just check if it starts with 2?

Comment: `if(preg_match('/2\d{2}/', $x) === 1)`?

Comment: @Cyclone Good workarround, but I feel like it's a cheap solution... what if they implement the 2xxx http code ? hehe :p

Comment: Seems clear enough to me.  I mean, that's the way to do it if you want numbers in the range of 200 to 299.  Maybe you want an intermediate variable isOK, and then you do other checks?

Comment: I think that by the time they implement 4 digit http codes, we'll all have to do some recoding anyway.

Comment: @FMax008: Rocket's comment only returns true on `2xx` codes. (Note the `{2}`)

Comment: What are these automated validations that make it impractical? I'm having a hard time imagining how `(x >= A && x <= B)` could really be that bad.

Comment: @webbiedave: Well, `2xxx` also matches because it does contain `2xx`. You'd need `^` and `$` to do an exact match.

Comment: If you want to check if the status code is in the range [200,300) , this is as nice as it gets. no need to obscure or make it complicated. You'll thank yourself in 3 months when you look at this code if you do not change it.

Comment: @pimvdb: Good catch. You are correct. Pattern should be `/^2\d{2}$/` or just `/^2\d\d$/`

Comment: What are your requirements? What is wrong with this code that we should avoid in our alternative suggestions?

Comment: webbiedave; yes, but I really feel that we're going overkill if we have to do a regex check to validate a simple number... As I agree with the @nos comment, I would still prefer the double condition. (But I think we can have a better condition without going obscure)

Comment: @FMax008: I don't think you should use regex either. I was just trying to explain the regex.

Comment: Got to love the perf numbers http://jsperf.com/test-if-range-vs-floor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In PHP (or any similar language), is there a better alternative to...

**No there isn't, in my opinion.**

Your code:

```
if (x >= 200 && x <= 299) {
    return 'ok';
}
```

is very readable and clearly defines what is being checked.

Comment: Hum I think your right... I'll think about it, but you might get the best answer ...

Comment: all other answers looks weird

Answer (score 8):

If you want a statement that you'll be sure to forget what you meant by it three months from now:

```
if(2 == (int)floor(x / 100)) ...
```

---

If nothing else, for readability's sake, wrap it in a function that describes it:

```
function isHttpSuccess(status) {
    return 2 == (int)floor(x / 100);
}
```

Comment: 251 % 100 will return 51, not 2. But if you replace the modulo by a division, and type cast the result to an Integer ... hum-hum, nice idea !

Comment: I did use: if(2 == (int)(x/100)) .. but I'm still thinking about unreadability comments... might be true... ( I voted them up btw)

Comment: Leave a comment that explains it. That's what I do when I write code I am not going to recognize

Comment: In javascript this would be: `Math.floor()`.

Comment: Just use a comment to explain. Something like: `// Although inefficient and confusing, I'm using the floor function here because I just couldn't bear writing another comparison operator, even though it would work just fine, avoids a completely unnecessary function call and actually makes it quite clear what is being checked. I hope this doesn't reflect badly on me during my next performance review`. Or something along those lines.

Comment: This fails if x is not an int. For example, with x = 299.5.

Comment: @JohnPS - I should hope HTTP servers are not responding with status codes that are floats. We'd all be hosed.

Comment: @Rob Hruska - LOL, sorry, if you know it's an int, then it's fine. I should stay out of php/HTTP territory. But why do you need `floor` if casting to `int`? Doesn't `(int) (x/100)` round downward already?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a function, you can use the return 'trick':

```
function getStatus(x) {
    if(x < 200) return 'status 1xx';
    if(x < 300) return 'status 2xx'; // will only get executed if x >= 200 as well
                                     // otherwise already returned '1xx'
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem with that code is that you need to define the 3xx range in order to have the 2xx range to work well.

Comment: @FMaz008: Well, you could also change that to `<= 199` and `<= 299` if that's what you're concerned about.

Comment: nice solution, but it still requires 2 ranges

Comment: @Darhazer: You're correct; it just does not require redundant double checks (like `if(... && x <= 199)` and then `if(x > 200 && ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Wow this thread is over 10 years old! Adding another answer is probably just beating a dead horse (awful expression) but here goes...

The original question was about PHP but the code example provided looks like JavaScript. Here are some ideas for both languages (although the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7449735/4484287) is likely the best—just because we *can* do something doesn't mean we *should*)

In JavaScript, strings are objects that provide quick access to characters by index, so this could work:

```
if (x.toString()[0] === '2') {
    return 'ok';
}
```

If, instead of `x` we passed-in `Response.status` or similar, the concerns raised about legibility become somewhat moot:

```
if (Response.status.toString()[0] === '2') {
    return 'ok';
}
```

In PHP

```
if (substr($x, 0, 1) === '2') {
    return 'ok';
}
```

or

```
if (substr((string)$response->getStatusCode(), 0, 1) === '2') {
    return 'ok';
}
```

To take it further (maybe too far?) we can write a function to resolve status code "[groupings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)"

```js
const getStatusCodeGroup = (code) => {
  const groups = {
    '1': 'Informational responses (100–199)',
    '2': 'Successful responses (200–299)',
    '3': 'Redirection messages (300–399)',
    '4': 'Client error responses (400–499)',
    '5': 'Server error responses (500–599)'
  }
  return groups[code.toString()[0]] ?? 'Throw IRL';
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if the error code was 20, or 2000?

Comment: Yes you can add a length check if you need to validate against out of bounds codes. The point was that strings can be coerced to behave like arrays in some languages :)

Answer (score 1):

When you repeat a task over and over, and want to reuse code, you should write a new function. These examples assume you want to use the `>=` and `<=` operators, although oftentimes I would use `>=` and `<` to include the min val and exclude the max val.

A PHP abstraction:

```
function between( $val, $min, $max )
{
  return $val >= $min && $val <= $max;
}
```

A JavaScript abstraction:

```
if ( !Number.prototype.between )
{
  Number.prototype.between = function(min,max){
    return this >= min && this <= max;
  };
}
```

For your issue of HTTP ranges, I'd use the bottom-inclusive form as:

```
if ( between( $val, 200, 300 ) )...
```

Of course it could make sense to change the order of the parameters so that the declaration is:

```
between( 200, $val, 300 );
```

But really it's up to you.

A further abstracted example:

```
function between( $val, $min, $max, $mode = null )
{
  switch ( $mode )
  {
    case INCLUSIVE:
      return $val >= $min && $val <= $max;
    case EXCLUSIVE:
      return $val > $min && $val < $max;
    case TOP_INCLUSIVE:
      return $val > $min && $val <= $max;
    case BOTTOM_INCLUSIVE:
    default:
      return $val >= $min && $val < $max;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function to make it easier:

```
function inRange(val,lower,upper) {
    return val >= lower && val <= upper;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
if(inRange(x,200,299)) {
    //execute code
} else {
   //other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in shorthand for this in most languages.  But there's nothing wrong with writing a clear utility function of your own, like:

```
function inRange( $val, $low, $high )
{
    return ($val >= $low) && ($val <= $high);
}
```

which you'd then use as:

```
if (inRange(x, 200, 299))
{
   return "ok";
}
```

It's pretty easy or a future maintainer of your code to get the gist of what you're doing here -- arguably even more so than with the original 'double-if'.

Answer (score 0):

```
return in_array($code, range(200, 299));
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
if ([199,299,x].sort().indexOf(x) == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you don't need the equality operator, all responses are integers.

```
if(x>199 && x<300)
```

is as simple as life gets.